# OpenCL Benchmark

Tags: benchmarking, opencl

I can read around a lot about OpenCL, and it seems to be the most promising (the only one?) multi-architecture library. OpenCL should be the first parallel architecture programming standard, and it'll be eventually adopted by the most part of programmers. That is good, ok, but is there a loss of performance by migrating from a native programming library to OpenCL? In the case of nVidia GeForces, I've already found an article were two realizations of the same program - CUDA vs OpenCL code - were compared and the first one seemed to be more performant. In the case of Pthread or Windows threads, I really have no idea, but I think that "generality" and multi-architecture approach will always have something to "pay".
Just to stop speculating about this or that, I'd like to check everything by myself, but I need you to help me! Is there an OpenCL benchmark set, universally accepted, I can use to compare with native code? Is there an analogous of CUDA SDK written in OpenCL code?
Thanks to everybody.

Comment: if any of the below answers answer your question give it a green checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no set performance benchmarks to test speeds of different frameworks.  Several benchmarks have been created.  Notable examples include the  [SHOC](http://tesla.parallel.ru/wordpress/wp_content/uploads/2010/08/shoc.pdf) benchmark suite and [Rodinia](http://tesla.parallel.ru/wordpress/wp_content/uploads/2010/08/shoc.pdf).  On the horizon, [OpenCL and the 13 Dwarves](http://developer.amd.com/afds/assets/presentations/2155_final.pdf) will likely be released soon, which could be useful for benchmarking purposes.

In order to do testing between frameworks, there has been work done testing the differences between OpenCL and CUDA in terms of performance.  Some of this work involves understanding that for OpenCL, while there is correctness portability, there is no guarantee for performance portability.  [Daga](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05102011-155739/unrestricted/Daga_M_T_2011_2.pdf) stresses the importance of architecture-aware optimizations in his thesis.

Comment: SHOC is a pretty great benchmark, developed by Oakridge National Lab. Here's an HPC wire article that I thought was pretty good: http://www.hpcwire.com/hpcwire/2012-02-28/opencl_gains_ground_on_cuda.html

Answer (score 4):

Not being a performance/benchmarking expert I can only try to give you a few general thoughts on OpenCL vs. CUDA. Fair warning though, I might get some stuff wrong.

The problem with benchmarks is obviously that you only can objectively evaluate very specific things - say, the same program done in CUDA and OpenCL, on the same hardware (as you named a source). But you won't be able to deduce from that experiment that you'll get similar results on another program, or with different hardware. Results will differ, so you would have to have a big test suite. This is what you ask for, but I don't know anything like that in existence - people will choose either technology for their bigger projects and won't write everything twice.

There are the NVIDIA Code Examples, done in both [CUDA](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples) and [OpenCL](http://developer.nvidia.com/opencl-sdk-code-samples). You could choose a few and compare your results.

I dont think that that would be time well spent, though. Maybe you should approach this problem from another angle: what can you do with one of the frameworks that you can't do with the other? They both use the same drivers, so both will support fancy technologies that come out with new hardware. Thread scheduling is done in hardware, so they have the same performance there. What remains to be tested are things like:

- will optimal code use all available memory bandwidth
- will the compiler create efficient code
- are you able to make use of all the compute units
- and so forth...

From my tests, the answer to these questions - will my code use the hardware optimally - is yes for both frameworks. So they definitely play in the same league, and even if one is 5% faster than the other for some specific problem at the moment, I thing it would not make a difference in a general view.

I intentionally didn't write anything about the other use cases of OpenCL, e.g. on CPUs. This field is much wider, as you have different OSes, even different OpenCL SDKs for the same processors (e.g. Apple and Intel) and lots of ways to parallel program without OpenCL (to compare to).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with everything you wrote, but I have some specific problems to solve. I know, a 5% faster isn't - in general - a remarkable speedup, but now I'm asking myself "ok, I have to do this computation. What hardware and what library am I going to use?" Obviously, I'll choose the faster solution. The dimension of my problem is not set, and maybe that 5% of performance difference can become "important". So, thanks a lot for your answer, I'll study OpenCL version of nVidia examples.

Comment: @biagiop1986: there is more than just performance to consider. Keep in mind that CUDA code only runs on NVIDIA devices, and OpenCL code can run on a multitude of devices INCLUDING those NVIDIA devices. This isn't an "all other things being equal" situation. Unless you're going to run a code once and never need it again, considering hardware compatibility can be really important. What happens when AMD releases a new card that's really fast? Or NVIDIA goes under? There's a lot to be said for hardware agnostic code.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking OpenCL and CUDA get the same performance.
There are not proper benchmarks, because simply can't compare different hardware and architectures.

If you are planing to write a GPU based app and just want to know wich one you should choose. Do not decide one or another just because of the speed. Compared to a CPU implementation both OCL and CUDA will give x100-x300 speedups.

My advise:

- If you are going to do a high level app, and you need lots of libraries, probably should use CUDA as it has a better SDK and support.
- If you are going to do low level app and you will write from scratch all the code, use OpenCL as it will support almost all the future hardwares (CPU and GPU). There are also some libraries you can use, but there are not as good as CUDA's.

Answer (score 2):

To be taken with a grain of salt:

http://clbenchmark.com/result.jsp

As NVidia card may have inferior support for OpenCL than CUDA, they *may* be ranked better with equivalent CUDA programs though.